# How do you check a checkbox in react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I cant seem to find much/any docs on this really simple thing I'm trying to achieve

I have a dropdown that is `display: none`. when I click a checkbox it becomes `display: block`
all I'm trying to assert is when I click the checkbox, it shows the dropdown

```
 expect(getByLabelText('Locale')).toHaveStyle(`
  display: none;
`)

getByLabelText('Locale').checked = true

expect(getByLabelText('Locale')).toHaveStyle(`
  display: block;
`)
```

the code works as expected but the test is failing on the second expect block saying: it should still be `display: none`

is the correct way to assert this?

when I click the checkbox it updates 2 attributes in my object to `true` which is how it renders in the code. when I manually pass these attributes the test still fails but it fails in the first expectation.

I feel like I need to do something like `setProps`

I have now tried to use `renderWithRedux` but it doesn't seem to be firing my action creator correctly?

is `fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('LocaleCheckbox'))` the best thing to try and update a checkbox?

Comment: According to your test code, the checkbox is invisible before attempting to change the "checked" value. How would  a user be able to click the checkbox if it were `display: none;`?

Comment: nah the dropdown was display none, although was so long ago now ha. cant' really remember

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To check or uncheck the checkbox using `react-testing-library`, you simply want to `fireEvent.click` the checkbox. There was a [discussion about this on react-testing-library Issue #175](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/175). In particular, kentcdodds said:

> this should probably be documented better, but with checkboxes you don't actually fire change events, you should fire click events instead.

But, based on the code you wrote above, what is the node with label text 'Locale'? Because if it has style `display: none`, how would your user click to check it? Is that a typo? You should be asserting style on your dropdown but clicking on your checkbox. Maybe I'm seeing it wrong, but it looks from your code like you're doing all your assertions and operations on the same node. That doesn't seem right.

I've written up a CodeSandbox sample which has a basic `div` with a style that is set to `display: none` or `display:block` based on whether a checkbox is checked or not. It uses `react-hooks` to maintain the state.

There is also a `react-testing-library` test that demonstrates asserting on the style, checking the checkbox, and then asserting the changed style.

The test code looks like this:

```
it('changes style of div as checkbox is checked/unchecked', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MyCheckbox />)
  const checkbox = getByTestId(CHECKBOX_ID)
  const div = getByTestId(DIV_ID)
  expect(checkbox.checked).toEqual(false)
  expect(div.style['display']).toEqual('none')
  fireEvent.click(checkbox)
  expect(checkbox.checked).toEqual(true)
  expect(div.style['display']).toEqual('block')
  fireEvent.click(checkbox)
  expect(checkbox.checked).toEqual(false)
  expect(div.style['display']).toEqual('none')
})
```

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction.

[image: Edit checkbox alters style]

Comment: sorry, let me explain better. I have a checkbox that is always is visible, checking and unchecking it, causes the dropdown next to it to be shown or hidden. i.e. checked == display block, unchekced == display: none. when I click the checkbox it fires an action to the redux store which changes the parameter to be either false or true. the component code then uses the redux state to display or not display that component, .does that make sense? I'm trying to test that when I click the checkbox the dropdown is either displayed or not

Comment: and it does not look like my action is being fired in the test code?

Comment: When you do `getByLabelText('Locale')`, are you talking about the dropdown or the checkbox? Because your test code is referencing it both for the style assertions and for checking/unchecking. That doesn't seem right. Any chance you have a CodeSandbox or other place where your code can be reviewed more fully?

Comment: I'm arriving late @RedBaron, but I think that if you are using Redux for this, you have to use `async` `waitFor`, `findBy...` and `await` statements since that process is asynchronous, it might be helpfull. PDT sorry for my poor English

Comment: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 6):

Using **userEvent** and **jest-dom** libraries would be a better approach.

```
import React from "react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { act, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
    
it("changes style of div as checkbox is checked/unchecked", async () => {
  render(<MyCheckbox />);
  const checkboxLabel = screen.getByText(/checkbox/i, { selector: "label" });

  expect(screen.queryByRole("checkbox")).not.toBeChecked();
  expect(checkboxLabel).toHaveStyle("display: none");

  await act(async () => {
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("checkbox"));
  });

  expect(screen.getByRole("checkbox")).toBeChecked();
  expect(checkboxLabel).toHaveStyle("display: block");
});
```

[image: test checkbox toggle]

Answer (score 3):

@samehanwar, thanks for your clear answer. I want to add something.

You don't need to use act() actually.
The reason why you don't need to do is the most of cases like userEvent, render are wrapped in act already. eventWrapper() in testing-library/dom is called when event functions like userEvent.

The answer should be like this

```
import React from "react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
    
it("changes style of div as checkbox is checked/unchecked", async () => {
  render(<MyCheckbox />);
  const checkboxLabel = screen.getByText(/checkbox/i, { selector: "label" });

  expect(screen.queryByRole("checkbox")).not.toBeChecked();
  expect(checkboxLabel).toHaveStyle("display: none");

  await userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("checkbox"));

  expect(screen.getByRole("checkbox")).toBeChecked();
  expect(checkboxLabel).toHaveStyle("display: block");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using  `"react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"`. I've manage to do the same with a simple:

```
getByTestId("data-testid").click()
```

this is the code to get the `getByTestId`:

```
const {getByTestId} = render(<Checkbox
        onClose={jest.fn()}
        onSave={onSave}
    />)
```