# React Testing Library: radio button clicked doesn't set checked on true after fireEvent.click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test a RadioGroup Component, initially, the first option is selected, this is tested and it seems to work fine.

Afterwards, the second option is clicked, the desired behaviour now would be to verify the second option if it has property `checked` set on true but it's not working.

```
  it('should select second option', () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <RadioButtonGroup
        options={options}
        label={label}
        onChange={onChange}
        selectedValue={options[0].value}
      />
    );

    const testId = options[1].value.replace(/ +/g, '-');
    const secondOption = screen.getByTestId(testId);
    expect(secondOption).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(secondOption).toHaveProperty('checked', false); // this works fine

    fireEvent.click(secondOption);
    expect(secondOption).toHaveProperty('checked', true); // this is still false
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check a checkbox in react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177928/how-do-you-check-a-checkbox-in-react-testing-library)

Comment: Can you add the code for the component your trying to test?